# Footer load before partial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

My view structure:

```
<header>
<body ng-view>(partial is loading)
<footer>

When I am refreshing the page for a second footer appears before partial, but I need in sequential order after partial footer load.

Was trying ng-cloak but no luck.
```

Please try to help me out.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you are using ng-cloak(which should work), be sure to load Angular before you need it.  In your case, load Angular in the <header>.  If you are loading Angular at the bottom, then ng-cloak won't be of any help.

Comment: yes i have loaded angular in header but still it happening...